# How to get version of PCRE (bundled with PHP) from code?

Tags: php, version, pcre

Is there any way to get version (and date of release) of [PCRE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) bundled with PHP from PHP code and store it into variable?

I can found it using [phpinfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) but can't find any other way to get that value directly from code.

I was trying to find solution last couple of hours but it's hopeless.

So far, I can get complete phpinfo() output in variable and pull out PCRE version/release date from there but I'm wondering is there easier solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [`ReflectionExtension`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionextension.php) class is made for this, though I can't seem to get the version out of it directly (`getVersion()` [returns `null`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Vx6xVV)). This [does work](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1uVEuZ) however:

```
$pcreReflector = new ReflectionExtension("pcre");
ob_start();
$pcreReflector->info();
$pcreInfo = ob_get_clean(); // Version and release date can be parsed from here
```

You'll still have to parse it, but at least it's just the relevant part and not the entire `phpinfo` output.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use constant PCRE_VERSION

[found source here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/183)